# error: expected ‘;’ before ‘printf’ C

Tags: c, loops, exception

hello=) with this following code i get the exception 
 *error: expected ‘;’ before ‘printf’*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    scanf("%i", &i); 
    for(int i=0 ; i<10; i++){

                if(i==1) printf("one");

               else if(i==2) printf("two");

               else if(i==3) printf("three");

                else if(i==4)printf("four");

                else if(i==5)printf("five");

                else if(i==6) printf("six");

              else if(i==7) printf("seven");

               else if(i==8)printf("eight");

                   else(i>9) printf("even"+"/n"+"odd");       
       }  
    return 0;
}
```

Can i sum up this code into a sorter form ? And why do i get this exeption?
thank you all

Comment: You can't have a condition for `else`

Comment: `else(i>9) printf("even"+"/n"+"odd");` This line has so much wrong with it.

Comment: And you can't add string literals.

Comment: Sidenote: what happens if `i == 9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some brackets "{}".
Code will looks better and will work.

```js
if(expression) {

} elseif(expression) {

} elseif(expression) {

} else {

}
```

PS. I know it will better. If this text be comment. But I don't have points reputation yet :(

PS2. @Myst if code will have 9. Code don't printf anything.

Answer (score 0):

`else` clause can't have a condition. So, you either mean just `else` or `else if (i>9)`.

Besides, C doesn't have + operator that concatenates strings. You can just leave out the `+` and the C preprocessor will [concatenate adjacent string literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) (see C11, 5.1.1.2, 6).

```
    else if(i>9) printf("even" "/n" "odd");
```